# Conditional display knockout js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have a condition where based on the data I have show or hide a span.

```
<span id="spanName" style="color:red" data-bind="text:$data.Name"></span>
```

If the Name is undefined , other than some value or "" I just need to hide the div. How do I do it knockoutjs?

Comment: Why mine answer is not the  correct? that have a sample and explanation about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, it uses the `visible` binding, so see that in the visible i call the observable, so with this we can verify the value of the observable. So in JS `undefined`, `null`, `0` and  `""` are the same as `false`, so for more information about that see the [False values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy):

```js
function viewModel(){
  this.text = ko.observable();
  
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```css
span{

  padding: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input type="text" data-bind="textInput: text"/>
<br/>
<br/>
<span data-bind="text:text, visible: text()"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [`visible` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html)

```
<span id="spanName" style="color:red" 
      data-bind="text:$data.Name, visible:$data.Name !== undefined"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also create a computed result

```
function ViewModel() {
      this.Name = ko.observable(),
      this.nameHasValue = ko.computed(function() {
            return this.Name !== undefined;
      }, this);
};

<span id="spanName" style="color:red" data-bind="visible: nameHasValue, text: Name"></span>
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that Name is an observable, you can set visibility by simply adding the following:

```
<span id="spanName" style="color:red" data-bind="text:$data.Name, visible: $data.Name()"></span>
```

Moreover, if you want to be specific on the requirements when visibility is true, then you can include conditions as follows:

```
<span id="spanName" style="color:red" data-bind="text:$data.Name, visible: $data.Name() != null && $data.Name() != ''"></span>
```

The above is useful if you want to include a check for strings that contains only white-spaces, or other criteria.